# DNS leak test shows other Google ISPs when I use Google 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 nameservers

Tags: dns

I am trying to fix a DNS leak.  I have changed the nameserver settings to use Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 public DNS servers.  However, if I run a DNSleak test it lists the following servers:

74.125.187.116  none    Google  United States

74.125.187.113  none    Google  United States

74.125.187.150  none    Google  United States

74.125.187.114  none    Google  United States

74.125.187.115  none    Google  United States

Although the IP address do not match 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, but the ISP is listed a Google. Does this mean it is working? Why is 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 not listed? Is it that the public DNS IPs are redirecting to other location specific IPs or is it that my settings are just not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, requests to Google's DNS are load-balanced across many servers. To cite from [dnsleaktest.com](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/what-is-the-difference.html)

> Even if you have configured a single DNS server, there may be many other servers that the request is passed on to in order to be resolved (normally to load balance the requests). For example if you configure Google DNS then you will often find 6-10 Google DNS servers which are fulfilling the DNS requests.

dnsleaktest works by sending a bunch of DNS requests to your configured DNS servers and performs Whois lookups on the IP addresses that answer.